# How can I display GeoEye1 imagery in colour in Opticks?

Tags: open-source-gis, remote-sensing, opticks

Anyone familiar with the use of the open-source remote sensing software [Opticks](http://opticks.org/confluence/display/opticks/Welcome+To+Opticks)? Im new to opticks, I load GeoEye1 imagery but it displayed as greyscale. It supposed to be displayed as bands combination true colour or false colour composites.

Answer (score 1):

Just do right click on the image and then select Properties:

[image: right click on the image]

If all the Display bands indicate the same band number the image will display in grayscale, so you can change it to the band combination you need.

[image: properties RGB band combination]

You can get more information about Opticks in this site: http://www.jenningsplanet.com/Training-and-Tutorials.87.0.html

Comment: Thank you Sigon :-D I appreciate your good answer. Will ask you another question about opticks soon.